# Show that $N=\{g_1^3 \times \cdots \times {g_r}^3 \mid g_i \in G, r \geq 0\}$ where $g_i \in G$ and $r \ge 0$ is normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

$N=\{g_1^3 \times \cdots \times {g_r}^3 \mid g_i \in G, r \geq 0\}$ where $g_i \in G$ and $r \ge 0$.

When $r=0$, we are to assume the product is the identity. All I am given is that $G$ is a finite group.
I tried the following:

(I) I tried to find $N$ as a kernel of a homomorphism but to no avail.

(II) I tried showing $gng^{-1}$ is an element of $N$ but I'm not sure that we can assume $g$ can be written as a cube of another element. I tried doing induction on the order of $G$ but that doesn't help either.

Any hints on how to proceed?

Thank you

Comment: First, can you show that $N$ is a subgroup?

Comment: I think that is clear to me. The identity is in N by assumption (when r = 0). When we have $g_1^3 \times … \times g_r^3$ and $h_1^3 \times … \times h_s^3$ then clearly the product is also in N and the same for inverses.

Comment: What does the notation $\times$ mean? Just the binary operation in your group $G$?

Comment: For (II) you don't need $g$ to be a cube; that could be false in any case.

Comment: @MoisheKohan - The symbol $\times$ is just the group operation.

Comment: $x^{-1}y^3x=(x^{-1}yx)^3$ and $x^{-1}yzx=x^{-1}yxx^{-1}zx$ should be all you need.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Wow that is very clever and simple. Thank you so much. I would have never come up with that on my own.

Comment: I'm sure you would have come up with it on your own, jmac, if you had taught Group Theory as many times as I have. Anyway, let me encourage you to write up a full answer and to post it here as an answer.

Comment: Today would be a good day to do that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Just posted it! Sorry, I'm a bit new to this. I will be more prompt in the future! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

As given by the hint from @GerryMyerson, we will show that for any $g \in G$ and any $n \in N$, $gng^{-1} \in N$

Noting that $gg_1^{3}g^{-1} = (gg_1g^{-1})^3$ and that
$gg_1^3g_2^3g^{-1} = (gg_1^3g^{-1})(gg_2^3g^{-1})$ we have that for $n = g_1^3 … g_r^3 \in N$ and $g \in G$,

$gng^{-1} = g(g_1^3 … g_r^3)g^{-1} 
= (gg_1^3g^{-1})…(gg_r^3g^{-1}) = (gg_1g^{-1})^3 … (gg_rg^{-1})^3 \in N$

Thus, N is indeed a normal subgroup.